# Finding the gem root

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a way to know the root path of my gem? I am trying to load a default config from a yaml inside the gems path. How do I get the gems root directory with ruby?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Given the following project structure:

```
your_gem/
  lib/
    your_gem.rb
```

Here's how I would do it:

```
# your_gem.rb

module YourGem
  def self.root
    File.expand_path '../..', __FILE__
  end
end
```

Ruby 2.0 introduced the [`Kernel#__dir__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) method; it enables a considerably shorter solution:

```
# your_gem.rb

module YourGem
  def self.root
    File.dirname __dir__
  end
end
```

If you need access to the other directories, you can simply build upon `root`:

```
module YourGem
  def self.bin
    File.join root, 'bin'
  end

  def self.lib
    File.join root, 'lib'
  end
end
```

Comment: Worked for me for referencing my "docs" folder included as part of the gemspec, where using the default Rails.root.join("docs") fails.  THanks!

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474). `File.dirname __dir__` does not work for me. I get this error: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String`. Happen to know why? Thanks.

Comment: @E.E.33, [`__dir__` is documented to return `nil` if `__FILE__` is also `nil`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__). How are you running your script?

Comment: I was just opening up irb and running the command `__dir__`. I just ran if from a file, and got the desired results. Thanks mate!

Comment: `File.expand_path('../', File.dirname(__FILE__)` is what I usually see.

Answer (score 32):

This is a universal solution for executables and libs.  It loads the specification using the Gem API, so the path is always correct:

```
spec = Gem::Specification.find_by_name("your_gem_name")
gem_root = spec.gem_dir
yaml_obj = YAML.load(gem_root + "/file_name.yaml")
```

Comment: Use [`File.join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-join) instead of string concatenation.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira why does it matter?

Comment: `File.join` ensures that you use the appropriate path separator for your OS which makes the code cross-platorm. "/" is specific to linux. Many versions (all?) of Microsoft Windows uses "\".

Comment: @JonathanR.Wallace - Agreed that File.join helps with platform/application compatibility, however the Windows File I/O API will convert any "/" into "\" that it finds in the path. That said many Windows apps that check paths will fail on a "/" instead of leaving the OS to decide what to do.

See note: [Naming Files, Paths and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths)

Answer (score 5):

`gem list <gem> -d`

Or if you're using bundler:

`bundle show <gem>`

Comment: Within the gem itself: im trying to call File.load. What is the gem root?