# How do I get Rails.root from within a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am creating a gem which requires a yml configuration file to be executed on load. But Rails.root is nil. My guess is Rails has not loaded and therefore does not have a root yet. How do I get Rails.root?

Or even passing a value to the gem on load would work too, if that's possible.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132949/finding-the-gem-root